# MVC4 cannot map object properties to JSON from AJAX POST

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Model:

```
public class JsonRequest
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(JsonRequest data)
    {
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = string.Format("Data: {0}", data.Data), // data.Data == null here
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: "Hello World!" }),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

JsonRequest object has an instance in Index action but it's Data property was not mapped to the passed JSON. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try adding `contentType : 'application/json',` in the ajax settings.

Comment: shakib: in that case JsonRequest data object is null

Comment: I think the method signature variable name `data` in `public ActionResult Index(JsonRequest data)` and `JsonRequest` property name `Data` is messing with the `DefaultModelBinder`. Can you name the method variable something other than `data` like `ajaxdata` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove JSON.stringify() call, because jQuery do it itself. And according standarts it's better to write {"Data" : "Hello world"} ("Data" in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Well you are specifying `data` not `Data` when passing the object back up to the server. This may be the root of the problem.  Also specify the `contentType` in your `AJAX` request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Data: "Hello World!" }),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: No, it's not case sensitive.

Comment: @ohavryl You need to take out that `JSON.stringify`, then replace it with `data: { Data: "Hello World!" }` then **it is case-sensitive**.

Comment: @Darren I added the contentType and replaced stringify call as you suggested and there is chrome error in console: chrome.webRequest is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.